# GZIP not working for Apache tomcat

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat, web, gzip

apache tomcat(8.0.36)

1.I have added .htaccess file in root then also its not working

2.I have added following code in server.xml

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
disableUploadTimeout="true" 
compression="on" 
compressionMinSize="2048" 
noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"  
compressableMimeType="text/html,
text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css,application/json"/>
```

Comment: Using .htaccess for gzip configuration is not reccomended
Perhaps you will get better results by settting the DEFLATE directives into httpd.conf and restart httpd.
This last step is required also with modifications o .htaccess
If still not working eventually post the relevant content of httpd.conf and httpd.ini or verify if they are done accordingly to this:
https://knackforge.com/blog/karalmax/how-enable-gzip-compression-apache

Comment: I have windows and i am not able to find httpd.conf ot httpd.ini there is httpd.html

Comment: Sorry that's my fault, I saw .htaccess and I did not notice you are not using httpd but tomcat. It has a builtin httpd somehow but Tomcat is ignoring the .htaccess and instead of httpd.conf use server.xml 
You can see the correct syntax here, https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/tomcat/enable-gzip-compression-apache-tomcat/ 
And yes, after you did the configuration change you need to restart the service.

Comment: plus, before you invest too much time into configuring tomcat 8.0.x, note that this version has reached its end of life and won't get any more updates. It's time to upgrade to 8.5 or 9.0